# Cannot find 'Greeting' in scope Kotlin Multiplatform Moblie

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I've added a KMM module in my Android Studio project. My project builds successfully. I have added shared module in your dependencies of

`App level build.gradle.kts`

it looks like this :-

```
implementation(project(":kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule"))
```

I am adding my project directory

[image]

My project inside this directory

```
> /Users/vmodi/AndroidStudioProjects/KotlinCocoapods
```

I created a xcode project and create a pod file using

```
pod init
```

**PodFile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'IosCocoapods' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for IosCocoapods
   pod 'kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule', :path => '/Users/vmodi/AndroidStudioProjects/KotlinCocoapods/kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule'

end
```

I run the command in new terminal and go to ios project directory

```
  cd /Users/vmodi/Xcode/IosCocoapods
```

then

```
pod install --verbose
```

[image]

My Ios project structure look like this

[image]

I open project and import module then I write `Greeting().greeting()` it gives error

```
Cannot find 'Greeting' in scope
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With Cocoapods you need to open `*.xcworkspace` file instead of `*.xcodeproj`, more info can be found [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html).

Then you need to run build with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. This will run a script that builds the KMM framework, and after building (if successful) and completing the indexing, you should not see any error.

Comment: Worked perfectly. JetBrains should update their tutorials to explain this.